# Accessing router with Ubuntu client from remote

Tags: networking, server, router, gateway

Is it possible to use my router Dlink-655 as a (gate)way to watch Netflix when travelling abroad?

In other words, can I connect to the internet abroad and from there to my router and use my router's ip address to access Netflix and other geographical services?

My laptop has Ubuntu 14.04.

What is the easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a free VPN service like hide.me, you can check it out, the free service limits the ip to US servers/ Canada servers so you can access your netflix account easily without bothering to connect to your router.